# What is the exact relation between the average kinetic energy of a system and temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I have just started studying thermodynamics and I have been taught that the Temperature of a system is a " measure" of the Average Kinetic Energy of a system but I wonder if there is an exact mathematical relation between the two?

Comment: $K_{tot, trans} = \frac{3}{2} Nk_bT$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases

Comment: This is what I needed!

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html